# JetTricks: Sticky Column gets sticky before it reaches the point where it should get sticky

Tags: wordpress, sidebar, elementor, sticky, jet-engine

This is how it loos like, red line marks where the column is placed and where the column should start to be sticky
[image]

So I want to make a sticky sidebar with JetTricks Sticky Column widget. The stickyness works but it gets sticky at the wrong place.

Anyone had this before?

Basically all I want is the red line to be the starting point of the sticky column. Somehow it stays sticky even if I dont't reach the red marker.

I tried to set the top and bottom spaces but it didn't help.